# create a folder share for each user and visible only to the user who has the right

Tags: powershell, windows-server, samba, windows-server-2022

I would like, under windows server 2022, to create a file share for each user, and that only the user can see this share.
let me explain, for example, I would like to create a user1 share for user user1, a user 2 share for user user2 and the same thing for user 3. But I would like users, when they go to \server, only sees their folder (that user1 only sees his user1 share and not the user1, user2 and user3 shares).
I tried to make a powershell script for this, but each user sees all the shares, whereas I would like each user to see only the shares on which he has the right to access... Is this possible? can you help me? thanking you in advance. Have a nice day!

ps: sorry for my english which is not my mother tongue

i try using this powershell script for doing it:

```
$Roofolder = "H:\homedirs"
$Subfolders = Get-ChildItem -Path $Roofolder
foreach($Subfolder in $Subfolders){
$User = Get-Acl -Path $Subfolder.fullname | Select -ExpandProperty Owner
New-SmbShare -Name $Subfolder.Name -Path $Subfolder.fullname -FullAccess $User -FolderEnumerationMode AccessBased }
```

Comment: Folder enumeration refers to the folders inside the share - you'll want to create 1 share, and then have a subfolder for each user at the root - with each user being granted NTFS permissions to only access their individual subfolder.

Comment: to be more specific, currently we have a netapp bay that hosts all of our users' data. This bay does file mode sharing, ie it directly manages file sharing.
It has an option called home_dir %w which allows each user, when he accesses \\bay_netapp, to see only the shares he has access to. to use my example above, user1, when he accesses \\bay_netapp, only sees the share \\bay_netapp\user1. User 2, on \\bay_netapp will only see \\bay_netapp\user2. etc...

Comment: Our new bay, not doing any sharing management (it does not support file, only block), so I set up a Windows Server 2022 server to manage the sharing. So I'm migrating all the data from one bay to another, and especially for user data, I'm using robocopy in the following way:
`robocopy "\\netapp_bay\c$\home_dirs" H:\Shares\Home_Dirs /E /copyall /b /efsraw /xo /v /log+:C:\robocopy_home_dirs.log`

Comment: So, my folder from which I have to share, contains all the users' sub-folders...
The goal is to try to re-find the same functionality as the old bay for users, hence the power shell script that lists the folders, and creates a share for each user. So that each user who accesses \\new_server sees only their \user share and not the shares of all users (as with the bay_netapp).

Comment: What you propose, and which is done quickly without the need for a script, would make each user access their data with \\new_server\home_dirs\user and no longer as before where the share was of the type \\new_server\user...
I don't know if I'm very clear lol...
But, I don't even know if it's actually possible to use the same functionality as with the old netapp bay.